# How to control screen blanking in Xfce

Tags: screensaver, xfce, xubuntu, blank-screen

I have a small cluster of machines running Xubuntu, all recently updated to 22.04.  The update caused oddities, different on each machine, but those disappeared after a restart.  But now I'm faced with a persistent problem -- a laptop that blanks its screen after 10 minutes.

It's a System76 Kudu, with two attached monitors in addition to the laptop screen.  I think it's nVidia, but I'm not sure.

When I look for causes of the problem (in the Settings submenu of the whiskers), I find multiple suspects, but none seems to be it:

1. Xfce Power Manager reports that it is not running, and asks if I want to start it (I don't).  It is also unchecked in the Session and Startup app, autostart tab.
2. LightDM Greeter Display Settings, Misc tab, Timeout until the screen blanks is set to "never".
3. Screensaver, Screensaver tab, is disabled, Lock Screen tab is also disabled.

These are all the things that stand out to me as possible culprits, but I don't see the actual cause.

How can I get it to stop blanking every 10 minutes?